# How to insert data of two tables in Firebase?

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am new to Firebase and I am planning to switch from SQLite to Firebase.

I have 2 tables in SQLite.

- First one is `NAME OF REPOSITORIES`. This will will be general for all users which is accessible to all the users of the application.
- Second one is `BOOKMARKS`. This will be specific to a particular user . I know that there is no table structure in Firebase .

Question is, how can I structure this type of data in Firebase? I have tried understanding tree structure of Firebase, but didn't get help for this type of scenario.

Comment: Have you tried going going through the [Converting SQL structures to Firebase structures - The Firebase Database For SQL Developers #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WTQZV5-roY)? :)

Comment: There are no tables in Firebase, but tree nodes

Answer (score 4):

To create two tables you have to create object of `DatabaseReference` for second table. Also you have to create second node.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

    //Create an object of DatabaseReference to create second table
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase1;

    private String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        // get reference to 'RepositoryName' node
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("RepositoryName");

        // get reference to 'Bookmarks' node
        mFirebaseDatabase1 = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Bookmarks");

        // Save / update the user
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                String confirmPassword = inputConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                // Check for already existed userId
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
                    createUser(name, email, password, confirmPassword);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creating new user node under 'users'
     */
    private void createUser(String name, String email, String password, String confirmPassword) {
        // TODO
        // In real apps this userId should be fetched
        // by implementing firebase auth
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
                /*userId store the unique key like KYNGnlMMIf3w11VukqD
                in this key store usename and email as JSON format in firebase cloud database*/

            // "mFirebaseDatabase" is for table1(i.e RepositoryName)
            //userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();

            // "mFirebaseDatabase1" is for table2(i.e Bookmarks)
            userId = mFirebaseDatabase1.push().getKey();
        }

        User user = new User(name, email, password, confirmPassword);

        //insert data in firebase database RepositoryName
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).setValue(user);

        //insert data in firebase database Bookmarks
        mFirebaseDatabase1.child(userId).setValue(user);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello at the first you should try with understanding the basic concept of denormalizing data. You can check one of the blog [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html).

Again, for more information of stucturing data in detail is [here](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data).

You can start structuring data using these links again. You have to have denormalised structure to developer best experience in firebase.

**Coming to you point, Two tables.**

You need to create 2 nodes in firebase. First one is with `NAME OF REPOSITORIES` and `BOOKMARKS`. If you are having any relations for both the table create a new node with that relation lets say `USERBOOKMARK` and try adding reference to the node.